# Does C# async await method run in parallel when called from within a loop?

Tags: c#

Background: I wrote a JavaScript version of the below code that gathers and persists weather data. Doing this took 25 minutes for the same data set.

Currently I have rewritten it as a C# .net core API. Performing the same overall task (yes with different code and language but an a similar implementation in terms of logic) is much, much faster at around 2 minutes. I am trying to understand why this might be and I believe it may have something to do with awaited tasks and the way threads are created and handled. Specifically I would like to know if the below code will create multiple threads performing the BuildForecast function in parallel which could mean that many HTTP requests are being made to my weather provider at the same time, which of course would explain why it is so much faster.

To be clear I do not have a bug in my code - my code is working - it is actually working far better than I expected and I am now trying to understand C# threading (I know that a Task is a way of monitoring and interacting with a new thread) and whether or not the below code will cause parallel execution.

```
var allLocations = await locationRepository.GetAllAsync();
var allCountries = await countryRepository.GetAllAsync();
var locationList = allLocations.ToList();
var countryList = allCountries.ToList();

// get forecast data
var weatherList = new List<Weather>();
foreach (var location in locationList)
{
     var country = countryList.First(x => x.Id == location.CountryId);
     var forecastResult = await BuildForecast(location, country);
     List<Weather> weatherForLocation = ParseForecast(forecastResult, location);

     weatherList.AddRange(weatherForLocation);
}
```

Comment: What else is happening in your loop? Could you at least supply a pseudo-code?

Comment: Question in its current state is unclear and a bit broad. Provide a [mcve] that can be used to better understand the problem and also clarify the statement about the performance.

Comment: [Tasks are not Threads](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benwilli/2013/04/24/tasks-are-not-threads/).

Comment: @HereticMonkey but they are sort of interfaces to get information about what is happening with threads right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation of the **await** function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/await), control is returned to the caller whilst the awaited operation is being executed. This is the reason why your loop will continue in parallel while `GetData(location)` is being executed. This is not an error, it is the expected behaviour.

To wait for `GetData(location)` to complete, remove the await operator and use the `Result` property as follows:

> `var data = GetData(location).Result;`

Here is a copied part of the documentation of await.

In the following example, the *HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync* method returns a *Task*. The task is a promise to produce the actual byte array when the task is complete.

> The await operator suspends execution until the work of the
>   *GetByteArrayAsync* method is complete. In the meantime, control is returned to the caller of *GetPageSizeAsync*.

When the task finishes execution, the await expression evaluates to a byte array.

```cs
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
      if (args.Length > 1)
         GetPageSizeAsync(args[1]).Wait();
      else
         Console.WriteLine("Enter at least one URL on the command line.");
   }

   private static async Task GetPageSizeAsync(string url)  
   {  
       var client = new HttpClient();  
       var uri = new Uri(Uri.EscapeUriString(url));
       byte[] urlContents = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(uri);
       Console.WriteLine($"{url}: {urlContents.Length/2:N0} characters");  
   }  
}
// The following call from the command line:
//    await1 http://learn.microsoft.com
// displays output like the following: 
//   http://learn.microsoft.com: 7,967 characters
```

Hope this helps.